# Delay in marking items in queue as exception - BluePrism

Tags: blueprism

I have encountered something that has basically left me scratching my head (BP 6.4):

**Description:**
I have a file with about 5000 cases. First thing the process does is to add these cases in the queue. But before it adds these cases to the queue, it cross references the case with a database to check if any of them are already closed. If their are cases in the file that are already closed (in my file there are 321 cases that are already closed), process does the following: it first adds all cases that are **NOT closed** in the queue and then adds all cases that **are closed** in the queue. Process then marks all cases that are already closed as exception in the queue

**Issue:**
I'm seeing bizarre behaviour at this stage: what happens is that when the process marks the closed cases (321 cases from my file) in the queue as exception, not all of them get marked as exception. I always get about 40 odd cases that don't get marked as exception. But if i check a few hours later, they are marked as exception. As I am stopping the process after cases are added and marked in the queue, none of these cases have been worked.. they just seem to take time before they get marked as exception

Has anyone seen this behaviour?

Comment: Would agree that this is curious behavior. It may be worth raising a ticket to Blue Prism directly, as Work Queues are more of a "black box" than most other components of the platform. It could be a bug, caching problem, etc.

Comment: With that being said, you can troubleshoot this by querying the SQL database after "most" of the cases are marked as an Exception. If you run `SELECT * FROM [BPAWorkQueueItem] ORDER BY [id] DESC` immediately after the cases are *supposed* to be marked as an exception, do these cases appear in the query results? If so, this issue is likely only cosmetic in nature. Otherwise, that ticket to Blue Prism is even more warranted as the cases are truly not marked as an Exception.

Comment: A less-bulletproof way to prove this out is to check the "40 odd" cases' "Exception Date/Time" in the Blue Prism interface, once they finally show up as Exceptions. Do they closely align with the remainder of the 321 Exception cases? Or do their dates appear "a few hours later" than the larger population of Exception cases?

Comment: @esqew: That is exactly what i was thinking (possibly a bug) but just wanted to check if I have missed something before I contact BP. Unfortunately i don't have access to BP database.. but what I am trying at the moment (which in a round about way is close to your DB suggestion): I will run a file with 321 closed cases only. Once completed, i will attempt a `Get Next Item`. If DB is marked correctly, i shouldn't get anything back and it's just a cosmetic issue (as you suggested)

Comment: @esqew: funnily enough, once the 40 odd cases are marked as exception, date\time of exception is set to exactly the time when the initial cases were marked as exception (well i say exactly.. round about the same time) and not 2-3 hours later when these cases were marked as exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63848225/delay-in-marking-items-in-queue-as-exception-blueprism?noredirect=1#comment112905459_63848225):

> once the 40 odd cases are marked as exception, date\time of exception is set to exactly the time when the initial cases were marked as exception (well i say exactly.. round about the same time) and not 2-3 hours later when these cases were marked as exception

Knowing this fact, it is likely that what you're observing is something purely cosmetic. Unless in your workflow you require this data to be up-to-date in real time, it is unlikely that this affects workflows' functionality in any material way.

Comment: So i loaded the 321 cases and tried `Get Next Item`. No item was returned. This indicates that this is more of a cosmetic issue rather than an actual issue (more details in my answer)

Answer (score 1):

While trying to investigate the issue (and navigating in **Control Room**), Bluprism threw the following exception:

[image]

Below is the actual exception detail (from detail section)

> ************** Exception Text **************
> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
> at System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem.set_Selected(Boolean value)
> at AutomateUI.ctlWorkQueueList.SetSelectedQueue(Predicate`1 pred)
> at AutomateUI.ctlWorkQueueList.set_SelectedId(Guid value)
> at AutomateUI.ctlWorkQueueManagement.SelectQueue(QueueGroupMember q)
> at AutomateUI.ctlControlRoom.ChangePanel(TreeNode node)
> at AutomateUI.ctlControlRoom.HandleAfterSelect(Object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
> at System.Windows.Forms.TreeView.OnAfterSelect(TreeViewEventArgs e)
> at System.Windows.Forms.TreeView.TvnSelected(NMTREEVIEW* nmtv)
> at System.Windows.Forms.TreeView.WmNotify(Message& m)
> at System.Windows.Forms.TreeView.WndProc(Message& m)
> at AutomateControls.Trees.FlickerFreeTreeView.WndProc(Message& m)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
> at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

It looks like ListViewItem threw a `NullReferenceException`. This could be an environment issue or connection issue causing this problem. I will contact support to investigate further

Saying that, as per esqew's comment, this is looks like a cosmetic issue rather than an actual bug